# Need help in creating setup file

Tags: windows, forms, installation

I have a c# project that uses a camera whose dlls are in C++(came with sdk of the camera). Obviously, visual studio is not allowing me to add it as reference to the project. So i used a wrapper which uses DLLImport and kept those dlls in bin folder so that the application will refer to them at run time (using wrapper class). This works fine on my x64 machine.
The camera is provided with x86 and x64 bit C++ dlls. I came across this situation where i need to place x86 dll in bin folder if i am running on 32 bit machine and put x64 dlls in bin folder when running on 64 bit machine.
So now i need to prepare a setup file which detects the clients machine (x64 or x86) and places respective C++ dlls in installed folder or dynamically refer to the C++ dlls location where its corresponding dlls are placed.

Can i get any help in accomplishing this? Is there any installer out there which can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you create an installer for each supported platform and the user is responsible of selecting the one that fits in his system. You can use Visual Studio to create a setup (msi) project.
Creating one installer for all platforms makes it difficult to maintain, and also will make your msi too big in size.

Comment: yeah.. I got the problem resolved. Its obvious that the msi becomes big in size. but the requirement is like that. What i did is...
Read the client machine whether it is x64 or x86 in code and define the search directory using 
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);